# What could cause water to not go into the gutters?

Tags: roof, gutters, rain

I recently installed vinyl gutters around the roof of my house, but after the first rain I discovered that the gutter doesn't seem to be catching a lot of the water. Much of the water seems to be dribbling between the gutter and the fascia board.  What is a good way to make the water go into the gutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like either the gutters aren't secured tight enough, or you don't have a drip-edge flashing between the roof and gutter. The drip edge deflects water out and away from the house trim and into the gutter. You install it under the shingles, pulled out slightly from the trim, and secured with roofing cement.

[image: Drip edge]

Comment: Thanks. The gutters are pretty tight so I think it must be the drip edge flashing. I have this kind installed already, but it seems pretty useless (http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/fa/fa2e5ae7-e4c8-4466-82a3-1cf424056ac5_400.jpg). Could I install the one you posted over the existing flashing?

Comment: @sam I'd try bending out the current flashing a bit to see if it gets a better angle into the gutter. But if that doesn't work, then I don't see any reason you can't install another over it.